# Windows and Ubuntu dual boot, can't add grub to uefi boot options

Tags: dual-boot

I try to set up windows+linux on lenvo p50.
Installation:

1. windows installation, installer also made 100mb efi partition
2. ubuntu installation, same disk

After that I would like to choose boot from "Windows Boot Loader" and "Ubuntu/Grub". However from the uefi I can only choose "Windows Boot Loader".

To overcome this I tried:

- use efibootmgr (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr) + install-grub from ubuntu live usb, to change boot order, but without effect
- reinstall ubuntu
- add ubuntu entry to Windows Boot Manager via bcdedit from windows (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-bcdedit-to-configure-a-multiboot-system-and-add-linux-4175644308/)

Did I made correct assumption that uefi can have both grub and windows boot loader entries to choose?
Did anyone had similar problem?

Comment: Chances are your UEFI firmware is bugged that boot entry cannot be added "manually" (as opposed to "discovered"; i.e., relying on standard and Windows-specific fallback path). Are you sure that you have installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode though? Check whether there's e.g. an `ubuntu` directory under `/EFI` *of the EFI partition*, assuming you only have one on that drive.

Comment: @TomYan I've got `ubuntu` dir in `/EFI`

Comment: Lets see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Can you manually add entry from UEFI settings? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492536/how-do-i-add-ubuntu-to-my-bios?noredirect=1#comment2615076_1492536

Comment: So have you checked whether your attempts of creating a boot entry has any persistent effect? I mean like do you see any new entry listed by `efibootmgr` right after your attempt, and also, whether the new entry vanish after a reboot?

Comment: @TomYan they actualy do not vanish, however the boot order does not work and added entries to `efibootmgr` do not appear in UEFI menu

Comment: @oldfred report https://pastebin.com/tzjBej4i and I could not resist trying repair (with no success) https://pastebin.com/jjLX2vSz

Comment: and bcdedit enum result: https://pastebin.com/QcMmXR7F

Comment: You show two entries, ubu & ubuntu for booting Ubuntu in efibootmgr, see lines 91 & 92/ Do those not show in UEFI one time boot menu? Some Lenovo have a locked UEFI, locked boot order,  or Device Guard that prevents updates to UEFI. Do you have that setting in UEFI? You may need to review manual to see settings.

Comment: There are something strange. First of all, `Boot0001` and `Boot0002` are indeed NOT in `BootOrder`, while they are apparently considered "active" (`*`). Some "inactive" boot entries are somehow in `BootOrder`. On the other hand, `Boot0000` points to the the/some second partition (`2`) instead the first one of the/some drive. (While it's weird anyway, you *could* have been relying on `Boot0019` to boot Windows.)

Comment: Not sure what's really going on here, but I would try deleting all the boot entries or at least `BootOrder` with `efibootmgr` if I were you. **I do NOT guarantee it is safe** (They should all come back after a reboot. Except the Ubuntu / manual ones of course. The Windows one (`Boot0000`) should also come back after you boot Windows once. You'll need to make sure `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` is a duplicate of `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` beforehand though, which should allows you to use the "(NVMe) drive entry" to boot to Windows before it comes back, assuming you can see it on the boot menu.

Comment: Or you may check first whether you can use `BootNext` to boot to Ubuntu. (`efibootmgr -n 0001` or `efibootmgr -n 0002`)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reset the BIOS to default settings (and changed default legacy+uefi to uefi only boot) and finally all boot options listed by `efibootmgr` and `bcdedit` finally appeared as boot options at startup.
After that I realised that there is "Boot Order Lock" option in UEFI BIOS - I don't know if it was enabled or disabled beforehand - I am pretty sure that I had checked all UEFI boot options (Secure boot, etc...)
Anyway, everything is working fine now.
Thank you all for very helpful advises!

One thing I am curious about - is it possible to add linux/grub option to windows boot manager - I tried this solution as aworkaround but it didn't work.